# Database Configuration Assist stuck at 36% while creating database

Tags: oracle, oracle19c

- I am creating a new database using Database Configuration Assistant.
- It is a Typical Installation
- The process is stuck on step 4/5.
- I am using oracle database 19c.
  [image]

I am posting this after waiting for 2 hours. Please advise me on how can I fix this :-)

Answer (score 2):

Down you have loacation of DBCA log directory and databases alert.log.
Most likely db creation failed due to some prerequisities (space, OS limits, ...).

Check alert log first, then check most recently modified file on DBCA directory.

Also, if you're installing on Linux, 19c is nearly 3 years old, lot of things changed since then. runInstaller has an option applyRU.

In worst case you will have to download recent RU(release update) patchset and let installer apply this patch before starting actual installation.

Comment: I am working on windows 10. The oracle19c was downloaded & installed 1 month back. The device has sufficient space and below is the message of last log:

```[progressPage.flowWorker] [ 2022-01-31 13:40:44.862 IST ] [InstallUtils.getOracleBase:489]  OracleBase from orabase C:\oracel_19c
INFO: Jan 31, 2022 1:40:44 PM oracle.assistants.dbca.driver.DBConfigDriverHelper constructLogAndMessageFile
INFO: Log Directory :C:\oracel_19c\cfgtoollogs\dbca
```